# Php File Size header()

Tags: php, header, readfile

```
$file_name = $_GET['name'];
$file_url = $_GET['file-url'] . $file_name;
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\""); 
readfile($file_url);
exit;
```

I'm using this code to download files in my site fetching from another web servers.

It works if my url looks like this:-

```
https://www.example.com/file_download.php?name=video_song.mp4&file-url=http://www.googlevideo.com/video/play/221589
```

So, it starts downloading by fetching the file from `http://www.googlevideo.com/video/play/221589` in my site. Now, though it downloads the file correctly, it does allow the downloader to see the actual size of the file. So, downloaders having problems with it (e.g. Time Remaining, Download Percentage etc.).

So what header should I use to solve this thing? Please explain it by coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
header("Content-Length: " . $filesize);
```

Comment: Very Very Thanks! :)